# Windows CLI command to list subfolders from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have below cli command to list subfolders from AWS S3 bucket which is linux based commmand.

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/foldername . --recursive --dryrun --exclude '*.*' | cut -d' ' -f3
```

but currently I am looking for CLI command on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS CLI is available on both Linux and Windows. The CLI command you refer to will work on both.

However, you are piping output from the AWS CLI to the `cut` command. That utility is native to Linux.

To use the complete command on Windows, you would install the `cut` utility. You can do that with GNU CoreUtils for Windows.

> CoreUtils for Windows. CoreUtils: collection of basic file, shell and text manipulation utilities. The GNU Core Utilities are the basic file, shell and text manipulation utilities of the GNU operating system. These are the core utilities which are expected to exist on every operating system.

See http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm